# Joi validate on enums as keys in a map

Tags: javascript, joi

I have a list of enums represented as strings

```
export const constKeys = [
  'A',
  'B',
  'C',
  ...
];
```

and I want to use Joi to validate that an Immutable.js Map has keys from `constKeys` and values of number. It looks like I can do something like

```
const myMapValidator = Joi.object().keys({
    A: Joi.number(),
    B: Joi.number(),
    C: Joi.number(),
});
```

but this method won't work well if `constKeys` is really long. Is there a way to just let Joi know the key has to come from `constKeys` and the values are numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You can use `mapValues` from [lodash](https://lodash.com/)

```
const myMapValidator = Joi.object().keys(mapValues(constKeys, () => Joi.number()))
```

Comment: Thanks it was helpful... Can you please give us some pointers on how you arrived at this fix?